# Shoulda statements are not executed in the order they are defined?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit, shoulda

I'm trying to implement [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) for test automation. I tried this code:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'shoulda'
require 'shoulda-context'

class TestClass < Test::Unit::TestCase
  context 'Languages' do
    should 'Ruby' do
      puts 'Ruby'
    end

    should 'Java' do
      puts 'Java'
    end

    should 'Python' do
      puts 'Python'
    end
  end
end
```

When I execute that code, it outputs according to alphabetical order of shoulda test methods:

```
Java
Python
Ruby
```

Actually, I want the output in the order I wrote the methods:

```
Ruby
Java
Python
```

To do that, what will I have to use in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it is preferred not to run test in a specific order. It is better to run them in a random order, because that allows you to recognize if there are tests that depend on other tests. If tests only pass in a specific order, it is a indicator that you are doing something wrong.

If you want to do that nevertheless:

```
class TestClass < Test::Unit::TestCase
  context 'Languages' do
    self.test_order = :defined
    ...
```

See: http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/test-unit/en/Test/Unit/TestCase.html#test_order=-class_method

Comment: I'd use "is preferred not to run". :)

Comment: Thanks spickermann. I tried your solution. But it's not working. I put test_order = :defined in my above code still should test methods are executed in alphabetical order.

Comment: My fault, please try `self.test_order = :defined`.

Comment: Now, it throws ``<class:TestClass>': undefined method `test_order=' for TestClass:Class (NoMethodError)` Now, I've another question, this ordering is not specific to `should` library. Here, it's related to `testunit`. Am I right?

Comment: What version of ruby do you use? `test_order` does not exist in 1.8.x

Comment: `ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]`

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 has only a hard coded order (see: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/TestCase.html), no setter. I am afraid it is not possible to set the order anymore. For a good reason I guess.

Comment: I do not know how important it is for you to run the tests in a defined order. And I do not know if RSpec is an option for you. But RSpec definitely accepts a `order` argument: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/command-line/order-new-in-rspec-core-2-8

Comment: spickermann, thanks a lot for your help! Actually, this is not important for me. I came across this issue while I started learning `shoula` I'll try with RSpec.